# Is it possible to debug other iOS applications with gdb/lldb?

Tags: debugging, ios, gdb, lldb

I'm wondering if it's possible to poke around at some apps running on an iPhone, both Apple's apps and 3rd party, and I was wondering if this is possible with gdb that comes with the iOS SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope!

You can't do it, because of the whole "get-task-allow" entitlement, not to mention no debug symbols in released apps.